# Power Query Sql.Database is slow when supplying an SQL string to the "Query" option compared to GUI-generated M code

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I am finding that using `Sql.Database` with the `[Query=<query-string>]` option is leading to much slower query times than using `Sql.Database` without a query specified and instead followed by drilling down into the resulting table.

For example, if I create an SQL query through the Power Query GUI, I can produce a query of this form:

### Query 1:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("SomeServer", "SomeDB"),
    SomeTable = Source{[Schema="SomeSchema", Item="SomeTable"})[Data],
    SelectedCols = Table.SelectColumns(SomeTable, {"a", "b", "c"}),
    FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(SelectedCols, each [a] = 1 and [b] = 2)
    Result = FilteredRows
in
    Result
```

However, if I select the "View Native Query" option, and paste that SQL code directly into the following query, this will result in a much slower result:

### Query 2:

```
let
    // this uses the result of the native query generated by Query 1
    sql_string = "
    select [_].[a], [_].[b], [_].[c]
    from (select [a], [b], [c] from [SomeSchema].[SomeTable] as [$Table]) as [_]
    where [_].[a] = 1 and [_].[b] = 2
    ",
    run_query = (sql_string as text) as table => Sql.Database("SomeServer", "SomeDB", [Query=sql_string])
    Result = run_query(sql_string)
in
    Result
```

In my case, with a more complex query producing over 1M rows, I am finding that the first query performs in 1-2 seconds, while the second takes nearly 5 minutes.

How can this be so much different if Query 1 is supposedly running a native query, and Query 2 is just initiating that same query directly? Note the database is in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the native query in the correct location, it will run fast. In the first step (Source) put your native query in the SQL Statement box like this:[image]

I don't normally execute the native query generated by the GUI, but it is a good indicator. If the last step provides a native query, it means the query will execute entirely on the server. If "native query" is greyed out in the last step, it means the query will execute on the PC. This means bringing the data to the PC for processing and can be slow when you deal with millions of rows of data.

I sometimes develop queries in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) then paste the resultant query in the SQL Statement box in Excel SQL Server database screen. I can use it as is or touch up the query further in Excel GUI.